# How to validate an employee's expense receipt for an Uber ride

Tags: united-kingdom, data-protection, employer

I believe an expense receipt I have received for an Uber ride from an employee is fake. Am I legally allowed to contact Uber and ask them to verify the receipt? If I suggest to the employee i think the receipt is fake that is a serious accusation. I would rather validate the receipt independently with Uber first. Is that possible/allowed because it's not my Uber account?

Comment: I've never used Uber, but I'm curious... I'm assuming that Uber drivers don't hand out receipts.  Did the employee print a receipt off the Uber website?  Alternatively, did the employee given you a credit card statement showing the Uber expense?

Comment: All receipts are available via the Uber App (no printed receipts). He printed a $341 receipt from the uber website/app and passed it to us as part of a monthly expenses claim. By asking for his credit card statement (which is also open to manipulation) surely we're insinuating we don't trust him?

Comment: It's obvious that you don't in fact trust him.

Comment: Could you not just calculate this yourself? A legitimate Uber receipt includes the time of pickup and where, the time of dropoff and where, and the amount of miles logged for that trip. You should be able to see the exact trip, using the drive time and miles to calculate the cost in addition to the base fee, booking fee, and possible surge price. It's pretty difficult to forge an Uber receipt. It requires a lot of realistic information, and being suspicious of it being fake would indicate to me you have very low levels of trust.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot validate it because the employee used his personal Uber account and Uber would breach customer's privacy if they told you about a transaction you are not a party to.

Consider using [Uber for Business](https://help.uber.com/h/827ebfa9-024d-4ad7-8c28-88681e1eb977) or give your employee a business credit card so that you could track the expenses.

Comment: Downvoter: Why the unexplained downvote? This answer seems reasonable.  If you think it is incorrect you should post an answer of your own or at least a comment.

Comment: A customer can provide instant permission for a third party to receive the transaction information. "Hi, I'm Lee Woodman, customer ID eleventy bazillion, I'd like to confirm a ride I took last Shroveday, can you verify that ride and cost please? ... can you repeat that for my manager standing here? ... thank you, have a great day!"

Comment: @Nij The OP ("third party") does not want the customer to know that they want to access the transaction information: _"I would rather validate the receipt independently"_

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Uber - that's legal. They can't tell you anything- if they did that would be illegal as it violates privacy law.

Comment: So let's say we went legal on it, would Uber then have to produce the receipt as part of that process? SURELY from their point of view there must be a simpler way?

Comment: If they received a subpoena then that would trump the privacy law - unless they went to court to argue that the subpoena was illegal, which it may be. I am assuming that the employee took an Uber from Bucharest to London because if you are talking about going legal for anything less than five hundred pounds you must have rocks in your head.

Comment: It was a $341 Uber Lux receipt.

Comment: If you think the employee spent an unreasonable amount on transport, then that is what you need to argue with. Not whether he or she forged the receipt.

Comment: Would telling the company that the receipt is a forgery be a privacy violation? If they said "the receipt that you have was not created by the Uber app"?